# Setting application screen display layer

Tags: python, display, video

I am displaying a video onscreen with omxplayer using '--l 0'

Is it possible to run a python program and set it's screen layer to > 0

Expanded info :-

I am running omxplayer from within a python thread using a command line request to display an mp4 video as -  omxplayer --l 0 fred.mp4

The python program is using pygame to render transparent surfaces that I wish to overlay on top of the video.

I have tried various methods, but non really allow me to use python to create the overlays. The python program does a lot of other DB work to gather the data for the overlay.

I currently have it working by restricting the video size in the omxplayer call. This allow the 'overlay' stuff to be displayed, as the video does not overwrite it.

Comment: Welcome.  You need to clarify the context: `omxplayer` cam be used directly on the framebuffer,  or within a GUI desktop session.  The answer here depends on that information.  You also need to explain what the python program is (Something that runs in a terminal? A GUI app? Something else?).  Please try to include and not exclude details.